# Oracle SQL like statement to use in a join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, wildcard

I'm trying to write a query in oracle with a JOIN to pull up necessary records.

table1

```
   Value      OtherValue1     
   123AB      Text
```

table2

```
   ValueDescription      OtherValue2
   AH/123AB/C/2020       Some text value
```

my goal here is to be able to join the 2 tables on table1.Value = table2.ValueDescription, something like:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.Value = b.Value
```

is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on b.Value like '%' || a.value || '%';
```

This is likely to have poor performance.

Depending on what you really want to do, you might want to include the delimiters:

```
Select a.*, b.* 
from table1 a join
     table2 b
     on b.Value like '%/' || a.value || '/%';
```